# How can I define generic routing in scala akka-http

Tags: scala, akka-http

I wanted to create the reusable the generic routing in Scala Akka-HTTP so that I could use same generic routing for rest of the routing I defined.

So far, I could define routing as below that works perfectly.

```
class TestApi(val modules: Configuration with PersistenceService)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) extends BaseApi with CirceSupport {
  override val oauth2DataHandler = modules.oauth2DataHandler

  val userDao = new TestService
  val testApi = pathPrefix("auth") {
    path("users") {
      pathEndOrSingleSlash {
        get {
          authenticateOAuth2Async[AuthInfo[OauthAccount]]("realm", oauth2Authenticator) {
            //auth => complete(userService.getAll().map(_.asJson))
            auth => complete(userDao.getAll().map(_.asJson))
          }
        }
      }
    } ~
    path("allUsers") {
      pathEndOrSingleSlash {
        post {
          entity(as[UserEntity1]) { userUpdate =>
            authenticateOAuth2Async[AuthInfo[OauthAccount]]("realm", oauth2Authenticator) {
              //auth => complete(userService.getAll().map(_.asJson))
              auth => complete(userDao.getAll().map(_.asJson))
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } ~
    path("user" / "upload" / "file") {
      pathEndOrSingleSlash {
        post {
          entity(as[Multipart.FormData]) { fileData =>
            authenticateOAuth2Async[AuthInfo[OauthAccount]]("realm", oauth2Authenticator) {
              auth => {
                val fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString
                val temp = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")
                val filePath = "/var/www/html" + "/" + fileName
                complete (
                  FileHandler.processFile(filePath,fileData).map { fileSize =>
                    ("success", fileSize)
                    //HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, entity = s"File successfully uploaded. File size is $fileSize")
                  }.recover {
                    case ex: Exception => ("error", 0) //HttpResponse(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, entity = "Error in file uploading")
                  }.map(_.asJson)
                )
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Here in the code I find `pathEndOrSingleSlash` and

```
authenticateOAuth2Async[AuthInfo[OauthAccount]]("realm", oauth2Authenticator) {            
    auth => ...
}
```

repetative.

I would like to get something like below to work with.

```
get(url, function)
post(url, function)
put(url, function)
```

So that I could reuse the repetative code. How could I achieve the generic routing as defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the `authenticateOAuth2Async`, `path`, and `pathEndOrSingleSlash` directives by using functional composition.  You can write a higher order function that will provide the "common" framework and then calls a function that provides the particular functionality:

```
def commonRoute(p : String, subRoute : AuthInfo[OauthAccount] => Route) = 
  authenticateOAuth2Async[AuthInfo[OauthAccount]]("realm", oauth2Authenticator) { auth =>
    path(p) {
      pathendOrSingleSlash {
        subRoute(auth)
      }
    }
  }
```

This can then be applied to your particular cases:

```
//example code doesn't use the auth variable anywhere, thus the "_ =>"
val getRoute : AuthInfo[OauthAccount] => Route = 
  _ =>
    get {
      complete(userDao.getAll().map(_.asJson))
    }

val postAllUsersRoute : AuthInfo[OauthAccount] => Route =
  _ =>
    post {
      entity(as[UserEntity1]) { userUpdate =>
        complete(userDao.getAll().map(_.asJson)
      }
    }
```

And then combined to form your final `Route`:

```
val testApi = pathPrefix("auth") {
  commonRoute("users", getRoute) ~ commonRoute("allUsers", postAllUersRoute)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Its working perfectly. But its not working for Path with following syntax: "user" / "edit" / IntVal since your code is using String. I tried with PathMatcher0 but again this might not only be the case.

Comment: You are welcome.  If you don't need the `IntVal` then what about `commonRoute(("user"/"edit"/IntVal).toString, ...)`?  If you do need the IntVal then you may need to abstract the path part out similar to how I abstracted the authenticate part...

Comment: I'll try and let you know

Comment: I couldn't make it work. I would appreciate if you help me in. commonRoute would accept Path in any format. For e.g.

commonRoute("abc" / "xyz" / IntNumber / IntNumber)

commonRoute("abc/xyz")

commonRoute("abc" / "zyx" / InNumber / String)

and So on

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that type of generic-y will work.  `"abc" / "xyz" / IntNumber / IntNumber` is a `Directive2` and `"abc/xyz"` is a Directive0.  So it is not possible to give an appropriate type to the parameter of the function you are asking for.  Most of the directives will work, but not `Path` since it is sort of a DSL.

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking same. Thank you for your effort. Appreciated :)